# Iterating over all squarefree composites $\lt L$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, algorithms, computational-complexity

I need to iterate over all integers that are:

1. Composite
2. Squarefree
3. Smaller than a limit $L$

And see for each one if it has a certain property (in addition to these 3). Then I need to sum all such integers with this property. The following code does exactly that:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        long L=(long) Math.pow(10,12);
        long [] primes = eratosthenes(L/2);
        long sigma=0;
        for (int i=0;i<primes.length-1;i++)
            sigma+=squareFreeCompositesGenerator(L,primes[i],i+1,primes);
        System.out.println(sigma);
    }

    public static long squareFreeCompositesGenerator(long L, long prod, int position, long [] primes)
    {
        long sum=0;
        for (int i=position;i<primes.length&&prod*primes[i]<=L;i++)
        {
            if (property(prod*primes[i]))
                sum+=prod*primes[i];
            sum+=squareFreeCompositesGenerator(limit,prod*primes[i],i+1,primes);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

The idea behind this, is that rather than checking all numbers up to $L$ if they're squarefree, I can rather simply create/generate them, which is considerably faster compared to iterating through all numbers up to $L$ and factor and check each one. In this code, a call for `eratosthenes(n)` returns a sieve of all primes up to $n$. The method `squareFreeCompositesGenerator` then "creates" all squarefree composites smaller than $L$, and checks if they have the property through the `property` method. Through recursion, it keeps multiplying the primes without repetition and runs through all possible combinations. The "Achilles heel" of this algorithm though, is in the very beginning, where I require all primes $p \leqslant \frac L2$. This is due to the fact that the largest possible such integer can be of the form $2 \cdot p$ where $p$ is the largest prime up to $ \frac L2$. The program runs swiftly even for $L=10^9$ but for $L$ as big as $10^{12}$, I can't create and store all those primes in reasonable time, and even if I could store them, it would still take a long time.

It is important to note I don't need to sum all squarefree composites $\lt L$, or count how many there are, but rather iterate through all of them and check if they have a certain property.

Is there any way to adjust the code so that it only requires primes up to $\sqrt n$? Or is there perhaps another approach to iterate through all squarefree composites $\lt L$ with a sublinear time complexity?

Comment: more of a programming stack exchange question, check out PARI/GP's forsquarefree and check the second element of number of elements ?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by checking the second element of number of elements? @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: it's PARI/GP related. forsquarefree returns the number, and it's factorization in matrix form.

Comment: I have a good factorizing program but I don't think it is the right way. Even with an efficient factorizing implementation, it would require $10^{12}$ iterations. Generating the numbers will be faster, rather than check each one for "squarefreeness"

Comment: Not sure if faster: One possibility I can think of is doing primality test on the residue. This way you would only require generating primes up to squareroot of $L$, say $Q$. Go through the sieve doing the multiplications: For an integer $z$ you would have computed the product of its prime factors of $z$ up to $Q$, without multiplicity. If the product $t$ equals $z$ then you are done. Otherwise you require $z/t$ to be prime, which you can verify with a primality test.

Comment: So the advantage is you don't need to store primes larger than $Q$. However you would have still computed them in a different way, via the primality tests. Moreover, for this method I think you probably have to sieve/"mark" integers that are not squarefree, otherwise you may be doing too many primality tests.

Comment: One other commonly used trick is not to compute the product of primes, but to sum the logarithms of the primes (so floating point addition). Then you compare the sum to $\log z$.  This is much much faster. However you need to be careful about the precision. If you are using this in conjunction with the idea above, a disadvantage is you also need to keep the array of primes involved to reconstruct $z/t$.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. but that "residue" needs to come from somewhere. So I will need to check each integer $z$ to see if what I'm left with after dividing it by primes up to $Q$, is also prime. It would certainly work, but I think it would be inefficient for such a large range. @YongHaoNg

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can relatively efficiently do what you're requesting by using that the set of positive integers which are composite and square-free is the same as the set of all integers $\ge 2$ except those which are prime or multiples of prime squares.

To relatively efficiently handle this exclusion, first use a type of [Wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) to determine, for some relatively small $n$'th prime $p_n$, the squares of the primes $p_1 = 2$ to $p_n$ multiples up to $(p_n\#)^2$, where $p_n\#$ is the [Primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial), i.e., product of all primes up to $p_n$. For example, for $2$ and $3$, going up to $(2 \times 3)^2 = 36$, the multiples of $4$ are $0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32$ and the multiples of $9$ are $0, 9, 18, 27$. Thus, any integer which has a value modulo $36$ of any of the remaining values of $1, 2, 3, 5, 6, \ldots, 31, 33, 34, 35$ will not be a multiple of $4$ or $9$. You can extend this to handle several more primes. I suggest using something like $(11\#)^2 = (2,310)^2 = 5,336,100$. Also, I recommend you just store the offsets (only one byte per value is needed since they are all quite small), with the last one wrapping around to the first, so you can just simply add the next offset to your current integer being checked.

Next, for the remaining primes up to the square root of $L$, you can store the squares of these primes in $2$ arrays, one for the square value itself (e.g., for updating the second array) and one for the next multiple of the square value to check. Also, keep track of the next prime square larger than the current value you're dealing with. This way, you can limit the iterations in your check loop, plus can just do comparisons, adding and/or updating values, with these operations all being relatively efficient.

With this in place, you can then just use an outer loop to get each next integer which doesn't have a small prime square factor. First, check if this integer is larger than or equal to the next prime (by having some sort of dynamic feed of prime numbers up to your limit $L$ of the next prime available to check against). If it's not a prime, then check if it's a multiple of a prime square (by checking & using those $2$ arrays I mentioned in the previous paragraph). If both of these checks pass, then if your certain property also passes, add the integer to your cumulative sum.

Factoring, which is generally quite computer intensive, is avoided. Apart from possibly the time it takes to check your certain property, one of the most computer intensive operations remaining is finding the primes. Fortunately, there are various techniques to do this quite efficiently. For example, there's Python bindings of a fast C++ primesieve library (with source) at [Github](https://github.com/hickford/primesieve-python). Also, I'm currently doing some primes research where I'm using a modified version of a relatively efficient public domain C++ implementation that primesieve provides of a [segmented sieve of Eratosthenes](http://primesieve.org/segmented_sieve.html). Note that, as stated there, the algorithm uses $O(n \log \log n)$ operations and $O(\sqrt{n})$ space. It seems your sample code is written in C#, so if you wish, I assume you can either use this in C++ or convert it to C#. On my computer (AMD Ryzen $5$ $1400$ Quad-Core Processor, $3.20$ GHz, $16$ GB RAM, $384$ KB L$1$ cache, $2$ MB L$2$ cache, $8$ MB L$3$ cache & running $64$-bit Windows $10$), it took my somewhat more efficient C++ version $0.672$ hours (i.e., $40.32$ minutes) to generate the primes up to $10^{12}$, and $15.342$ hours to generate the primes up to $2.1 \times 10^{13}$.

Comment: To start off, thank you. I've been trying to absorb all of it for the past day. Not all concepts are clear to me. First of all, I use Java. I don't think there exists any type of object that can store more than $2^31$ values, even if I have sufficient memory. I am yet to overcome that problem. Secondly, I don't get anywhere near the insane performances that you are talking about. At first I tried to translate this into Java (the latter - the segmented sieve), and I got very slow performance. Then I simply copy-pasted it to Visual Studio to see if perhaps the language is bad.

Comment: But even there, running the exact same code provided in github, generating all primes up to $10^8$ takes over 10 seconds, which is another problem that I am not able to solve. I don't know why I am getting such slow performances. Because of this, I could not implement the first ideas that you mentioned, as they require these primes to be generated as well. For the sake of this discussion, let's assume I manage to generate and store all the primes up to $L/2$, Do you know the time and space complexity of this algorithm? Do you know what' s causing these very slow performances of sieving primes?

Comment: @MCFromScratch You're welcome for the help. Note I never actually ran their sample code as it's not the most inefficient. I made several improvements, with the most major one being to use bits instead of bytes, as they suggest later themselves & even provide a sample C++ program. This should give you considerably better results. As for why your machine is so relatively slow, my best guess is that you have very little memory cache. My testing with trying to improve the speed of my primes program showed how important this is. I even upgraded my machine to get more memory cache so I could ...

Comment: @MCFromScratch (cont) get better performance. You may wish to check on your machine. If that is the issue, then using bits instead of bytes, as mentioned earlier, should help. Also, you may wish to try the considerably faster primesieve library. As for the limit of getting the primes, note you need to get them for up to $L$, not $L/2$, if you use what I'm suggesting, so you can determine & discard the larger primes. Re: the space & time, it should be basically what is required for the primes themselves, i.e., $O(n \log \log n)$ for time & $O(\sqrt{n})$ for the space. Finally, C# & Java are ...

Comment: @MCFromScratch (cont.) quite similar languages. I'm sorry for mistaking them. Regarding Java's limit of native integer types only allowing up to $2^{31}$, note it's been over $20$ years since I last programmed in Java, so I'm not up to speed. Regardless, like in C++ or other languages, you can extend the size, if you really want & need to, but using specialized code. I'm quite certain there would be some specialized publicly available libraries to use if you wish. One final thing is although what I suggest allows you to get square-free very fast, be careful with certain implementation details.

Comment: @MCFromScratch Sorry for so many comments, but first I just checked &, from [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), Java supports a "long" data type of $64$ bit integers. Next, with getting primes, I got some improvement by using pre-allocated, fixed size arrays instead of STL classes used in the sample code, but it's relatively minor. Instead, this may seem obvious to you, but running a debug version in VS's debugger is *much* slower (even about $10$ sec. as you saw) than a command-line release version. Good luck with resolving this.

Comment: To properly implement and try this method for my original problem, I first need to be able to efficiently generate the primes, as we agree. What I meant, is that Java doesn't allow **storage** of more than $2^{31}$ values. They can be as long as 100 digits, but only $2^{31}$ of them. For example, arrays can't be refered to with and index larger than $2^{31}$, as they may only have up to $2^{31}$ cells, regardless of what they contain. For the limit I mention, $\pi (x)$ is bigger than that, which means, with my current knowledge, that I can't store all of them. How can I get past that?

Comment: @MCFromScratch Thanks for clarifying your previous statement. Using my suggested method, you don't need to store all of the primes. Instead, for example, for getting the squares of the primes up to $L$, you only need to get & store the primes up to $\sqrt{L}$ in $2$ arrays, as I stated. Then, for the next stage of actually determining all of the composite, square-free integers, you can rerun & only need to get the primes dynamically as you go along. The segmented sieve idea, by default, only needs $O(\sqrt{L})$, but you can use less if you want. Please reread & see if this makes sense to you.

Comment: @MCFromScratch With getting the primes, you will need to change the sample segmented sieve code, if you're using that, to have each next prime be given on demand, by either going to the next prime in the segment or refilling the segment & then giving it's first prime. This is what I did. Also, when I wrote you can reduce the space required, apart from using bits vs. bytes, I was referring to the segment size. You can actually make it quite small. I tested it with something very small, I think about only $10$ or $20$, with it working, but quite slowly, so you don't want to make it too small.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 N = 20; mu = [1,-ones(1,N-1)]; primes = [0,ones(1,N-1)]; 
 for n = 2:N, 
   mu(n+n:n:end) = -mu(n) + mu(n+n:n:end); primes(n+n:n:end) = 0; 
 end; 
 squarefree = abs(mu); find(primes==1), find(squarefree==1)
```

on  https://octave-online.net/

Comment: It's a good way to look at the smaller numbers but for that range I am afraid it is not good enough

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion here about primes, including python code for popping out squarefree integers. There is a prime generator which serves as the basis for the square factor sieve included.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900585/4363639